# React Date picker question: How to display date in proper format in a table?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

My Date picker works fine and displays date in the form in desired format which is MM/DD/YYYY. This is my code:

createEvent.js is as follows:

```
<div className="form-group">
   <label>Select Date: </label>
    <br></br>
    <DatePicker
      selected={ this.state.startDate }
      onChange={ this.handleChange }
    />
</div>
```

However when I am displaying it in a table, it displays the date in a long string like 2018-12-31T08:00:00.000Z

Here is my code for TableA.js:

```
class TableRow extends Component {
    render() {
     return (
       <tr>
        {this.props.obj.eventname}
      </td>
      <td>
        {this.props.obj.sDate}
      </td>
    </tr>
);} }
```

Is there a way in which I can display this properly? I have tried to use sDate.toString() in my table as well as sDate.toLocaleDateString() but my application does not recognize these two commands and gives me error. Do I need to include a library in table.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dealing with a timestamp string, and you want to format it, one option is to use the MomentJS library, available as the `moment` npm package.

One strategy for fitting this code into your app could be:

```
// in CreateEvent component: 

handleChange = event => {
  const aMomentObject = moment(event.target.value)  
  const aFormattedString = aMomentObject.format("MM/DD/YYYY")

  let obj = this.state.obj
  obj.sDateFormatted = aFormattedString

  this.setState({ obj: obj})
}

// in TableRow component

render () {
  // ...
  <td>{ this.props.obj.sDateFormatted }</td>
  // ...  
}
```

Or, if you don't want to complicate your state by adding properties, you can perform the conversion when the value is being rendered, like:

```
// in TableRow component:  

import moment from 'moment'

class TableRow extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // ...
      <td>{ moment(this.state.obj.sDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY") }</td>
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The second solution of changing TableRow component worked for me. Just had to change 'state' to 'props'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the date is a `Date` object, you need to format it. As a first iteration, this will get you a date like `1/5/2018`:

```
<td>{{this.props.obj.sDate.getMonth() + 1}}/{{this.props.obj.sDate.getDate()}}/this.props.obj.sDate.getYear()}}</td>
```

We do this by taking the month as a number (January is 0, February is 1, and so on so we need to add 1), adding a `/`, adding the day of the month, adding another `/`, and then the year.

To turn this into something like `01/05/2018`, we need to pad the numbers with 0. Of course we could do it like this:

```
<td>0{{this.props.obj.sDate.getMonth() + 1}}/0{{this.props.obj.sDate.getDate()}}/this.props.obj.sDate.getYear()}}</td>
```

But then double digits will cause dates like `012/012/2018` which is even worse. To get around this, we can check if the number is `>=` 9. To make this a little bit nicer to read, I'll write it as a function too.

```
function formatDate(d) {
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = d.getDate();
  var year = d.getYear;

  var out = month < 10 ? '0' : ''; // If the month < 10, start with a 0
  out = out + month + '/'; // Add the month to the string and a slash
  out = out + (day < 10 ? '0' : ''); // Add a 0 if day < 10
  out = out + day + '/' + year; // Finish it off with the rest of the day and year.
}
```

So, to get your format, you can do something like

```
<td>{{ formatDate(this.props.obj.sDate) }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

jst try this...

```js
import moment from 'moment';

let date='2018-12-31T08:00:00.000Z';

let formatedDate= moment(date).format('MM DD YYYY');
```